# Sublime Text not compiling multi-file projects in C++

Tags: c++, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I am to compile a multi-file C++ program, and have the following error;

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "included::printMSG()", referenced from:
      _main in ccQwMj1l.o
ld: symbol(s) not[Finished in 0.3s with exit code 1] found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My code:
main.cpp: https://gist.github.com/3845822

included.cpp: https://gist.github.com/3845825

included.h: https://gist.github.com/3845827

(confirmed to work with `g++`)

EDIT: I am not putting these files in a project, they are just all in the same folder, and I'm compiling `main.cpp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just compile a single file and hope all other files are automatically linked to it to create the final program.

One way to make that happen is to use a program called [`make`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29), which reads a `Makefile` that has rules that `make` follows`.

A simple `Makefile` can look like this:

```
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -g

my_pogram: main.o other_file.o third_file.o
    g++ main.o other_file.o third_file.o -o my_program

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o main.o main.cpp

other_file.o: other_file.cpp
    g++ $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o other_file.o other_file.cpp

third_file.o: third_file.cpp
    g++ $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o third_file.o third_file.cpp
```

There are other similar programs to handle this. One that is popular is [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/).

Comment: Does SublimeText not automatically link the files to it? It works fine in windows, according to my friends. Unless thats MinGW compiling those files with it... EDIT: It turns out they didn't use SublimeText... :(

Comment: @jackwilsdon No, Sublime Text is purely a text editor, not an [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment). It can call external programs, but that's about it.

Comment: Does Sublime Text support Makefiles? I'd rather run it all in one place, and I like sublime text, even if it is purely a text editor with some 'frilly bits' added.

Comment: @jackwilsdon Yes it does natively. Look in the "Tools/Build Systems" menu.

Comment: In the end I moved to a proper IDE, Code::Blocks :)
Thanks Joachim!