# Instantiation of inner class : "Undeclared identifier"

Tags: c++, class, inner-classes

This might be a simple mistake but I can't understand why the following compiles fine, which I expected:

```
class Foo {
public:
    class Bar {
    public:
        Bar(unsigned int a, unsigned int b) { }
    };
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Foo::Bar blah(1, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

While this does not compile:

**A.cpp**

```
#include "B.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Foo::Bar blah(1, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

**B.h**

```
#ifndef A_INCLUDED
#define A_INCLUDED

class Foo {
public:
    class Bar {
    public:
        Bar(unsigned int a, unsigned int b);
    };
};

#endif
```

**C.cpp**

```
#include "B.h"

Foo::Bar::Bar(unsigned int a, unsigned b) {

}
```

Generates the following build error using GCC 4.8.1 (with Sublime Text 3 as IDE)

> C:\Users\ALEXAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMujUOG.o:A.cpp:(.text+0x2b):
>   undefined reference to `Foo::Bar::Bar(unsigned int, unsigned int)'
>   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status [Finished in 0.3s]

Of course, the second snippet should be equivalent to the first but deconstructed in more files because obviously the "real code" I want to use is larger than this example.

Comment: Looks like it compiles fine. It just doesn't link.  You need to link to C.cpp, but also what's up with this: : a(0), b(0)

Comment: Just as I thought, this would be an error on my part when configuring the project in Sublime Text, hence why I mentioned it. I will try to look in that direction.

Comment: The a(0)... I removed in my code but forgot to remove it here. Thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: @AlexanderPLevasseur I have nominated the question for closing as duplicate. Glad you got it sorted

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @thang, this was a linker issue. Sublime Text is more of a text processor with some IDE features than a real IDE. It does a good job building single files but cannot build multiple-file projects as stated here:

[Sublime Text not compiling multi-file projects in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12763122/sublime-text-not-compiling-multi-file-projects-in-c)

What resolved the problem for me was to use the command line and then use the following command:

```
g++ C.cpp A.cpp -o test
```

Answer (score 0):

try to separate the classes and instantiate the class with:
new

Sometimes the compiler complains about inner classes,

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps, for elaboration:

1. Compile your implementations

   g++ -c C.cpp A.cpp
2. Link to create the exe

   g++ -o myexe C.o A.o